# Comment dire l'expression anglaise « Who wouldn’t? » en français ?

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, constructions

J'aimerais un équivalent de :

> “I need money.”
>   “Who wouldn't?”

Cette réponse suggère « tout le monde à besoin d'argent ».

La phrase « Qui ne l'aurait pas ? » m'est venue à l'esprit, mais je n'en suis pas sûre.

> — J'ai besoin d'argent.
>   — Qui ne l'aurait pas ?

Comment: I would sooner say, "Who _doesn't_?" In English. I'm not sure you can say just say it word for wed in French. You could say, "Qui n'en a pas besoin ?"

Comment: Faut-il donc répéter le mot "besoin" ?

Comment: Oui, car "Qui n'en a pas ?" sous entendrait "Qui n'a pas d'argent ?"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, "Qui ne l'aurait pas ?" is not appropriate here. As a native French speaker it took me some time to understand that sentence. It is true that in the locution "avoir besoin" uses the verb "avoir", and grammatically I don't think there is a problem with your sentence. But "avoir" is so tightly linked with the word "besoin" that the sentence stops making sense if you remove it.

If you want to translate the sentence more-or-less literally, you can use "Qui n'en a pas besoin ?" as cccg03 suggests in the comments. One could also say "Comme tout le monde", which has a slightly different meaning but feels a bit more idiomatic.

Comment: An alternative I sometimes hear to "comme tout le monde": *on en est tous là*.

Comment: @Greg Hi. When I hear "on en est tous là", the idea of "ah, we've all been there" comes to mind instead. Such as: "J'espère que ce n'est qu'une phase passagère. Enfin, on en est tous là" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another option with a slightly different meaning would be:

*A qui le dis-tu?*

This literally means "Who are you telling?", but can be used in French if you are in the same situation as the person making the statement.

If both person A and person B were in need of money, the following would be appropriate:

A: "J'ai besoin d'argent."

B: "A qui le dis-tu?"